# Uploading multiple photos using iPhone Camera at once

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement a functionality where user can take multiple photos one by one on their iPhone device and upload all at once on to the server.

I was able to successfully do the multi selection of photos from gallery using ELCImagePickerController.

However I am unable to figure out, how I should do this using the iPhone camera. 
Though, I am trying to do this using Xamarin.iOS the code snippet in Swift would also be fine as I can easily translate it in to C#. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, would work, I can convert to c#. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I am basically looking for a way to capture photos one by one using camera, then a "upload" button somewhere on on an overlay view. Uploading functionality with multiple images is already implemented.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/intro_to_manual_camera_controls/